# Vue unit test: beforeEach() executing after all tests, not before each test

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to write a few unit tests for Vue and instead of setting up a new wrapper each time, I'd like to use beforeEach() to take care of it automatically. When I run the debugger, it fails all of the tests, then runs the beforeEach() function for each of the tests.

This is my .spec.js file.

```
import  {
  mount,
} from '@vue/test-utils';
import  QcAddressView from './address-view.vue';
const id = 'test_address-view';

describe('qc-address-view', () => {
  let wrapper = null

  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log("beforeEach executed!");
    wrapper = mount(QcAddressView, {
      id,
      address: {
          addrLine1: '111 Testerson Way',
          addrLine2: '',
          cityName: 'Olympia',
          stateCode: 'WA',
          zipCode: '98512',
          countyName: 'Thurston',
          countryName: 'United States of America',
      },
    })
  })

  test('sets up a valid address', () => {
    console.log('sets up a valid address');
    expect(wrapper.attributes('id')).toBe(id);
  })
});
```

The console shows me the test fails:

```
FAIL: qc-address-view
× sets up a valid address (72ms)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addrLine1' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of null
```

It can't read the properties because beforeEach() hasn't set up the object yet.

Then it runs beforeEach() after the test instead of before it:

```
console.log: beforeEach executed!
```

When I tried it with three tests, it would fail each test, then console.log would print "beforeEach executed!" three times.

How do I get beforeEach() to run before each test, instead of each one after all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to put the `id` and `address` into an `attrs` object, thus:

```
wrapper = mount(QcAddressView, {
  attrs: {
    id,
    address: {
      addrLine1: '111 Testerson Way',
      addrLine2: '',
      cityName: 'Olympia',
      stateCode: 'WA',
      zipCode: '98512',
      countyName: 'Thurston',
      countryName: 'United States of America',
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`beforeEach` *is* actually running before your tests. Otherwise, `wrapper` would be `null` in your test, and you'd get a different error.

You're seeing the console logs *after* the test because [Jest buffers the log output](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5281), and dumps it at the end of the tests. You can avoid the bufferring by setting [`useStderr`](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--usestderr). You can do this from `jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  useStderr: true,
}
```

Comment: Good one on useStderr.